# usps method is not showing in front end in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento

i have apply "usps" method , all information is correct in backend ,but why no-one method are showing?
any information which USPS method will display in this time?
i have apply 
Express mail
Parsal post
Priority mail
but no -one is showing

Comment: please check var/log/ for error and post it here

Comment: check that it's set in all scopes - maybe it's enabled in "Default" but disabled in website?

Answer (score 0):

tyr this link...and create a module

https://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-hide-shipping-method-on-magento-frontend-but-leave-it-on-in-admin-area/